# IOS Low Power mode stops video autoplay in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, video, media

I am developing a website and I am using a video as my hero container in my main page. The video is set to autoplay as soon as the page loads. On IOS low battery mode, I found out that it stops video autoplay in order to save battery life. What are my possible solutions to fix this problem.

The play button is shown on the video. Is it possible to force the video to play or even hide the playbutton of the video?
Is there any event listeners that work aside from suspend because that did not work for me.